# Showing and Hiding of Objects in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

I would like to show and hide the objects (divs, texts or btns) according to some conditions.

In C#, we can write like the following to reduce amount of codings:

```
txtA.visible = (type == "A");
txtB.visible = (type == "B");
txtC.visible = (type == "C");
```

In JQuery, to show and hide, I use .show() and .hide() methods.
But, I have to write many lines for that simple feature.  For eg:

```
if (type == "A")
   $("#txtA").show();
else
   $("#txtA").hide();

if (type == "B")
   $("#txtB").show();
else
   $("#txtB").hide();

if (type == "C")
   $("#txtC").show();
else
   $("#txtC").hide();
```

Is there anyway to achieve the same functionality with fewer lines?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`.toggle(showOrHide)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) allows for a boolean to show or hide the element.

You could rewrite your example to look like this:

```
$("#txtA").toggle(type === "A");
$("#txtB").toggle(type === "B");
$("#txtC").toggle(type === "C");
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/xBVmx/)**

Answer (score 6):

Use the ternary operator:

```
(type == "A") ? $("#txtA").show() : $("#txtA").hide();
```

Comment: I don't see how this would reduce code such much when you have lots of elements, it's just adding conditional on one line. `if (type == "A") $("#txtA").show(); else $("#txtA").hide()` is almost as short.

Comment: @Gary Green - I like your solution better

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [JQuery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)!

Comment: I think that won't reduce code size in this case, since the toggling is occurring conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

This will show the current type and hide all siblings elements (I assume they are placed inside a container)

```
// Remember ids are case sensitive
var type = 'A';

$('#txt' + type).show() // Show the current type
  .siblings().hide();  // Hide all other elements
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/4JkGm/

If your sibling elements aren't always the type you want to hide just tag a filter onto it:

```
$('#txt' + type)
  .show() // Show the current type
  .siblings()
  .filter(function() {
      return (this.id.match(/^txt[A-C]$/))
  }).hide(); // Hide all other elements
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/4JkGm/1/