# JQuery Toggle and Show Slow / Fast

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I want to toggle objects using JQuery.  I can just only show/hide objects and I want to show/hide them slowly rather than immediately.

[Showing and Hiding of Objects in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280499/showing-and-hiding-of-objects-in-jquery)

```
$("#txtA").toggle(type == "A");
```

I don't know how to add ".show('slow')" on the above code.  Please help me.   Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer. You simply can't add the duration parameter to the above code, because it expects only a boolean, the way you are calling it. If you want to change the duration you should do it in an if/else block statement. You can change the duration in milliseconds within the parentheses of `.show()` or `.hide()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) says that there is no overload for `.toggle` that both takes a boolean *and* allows you to specify an easing parameter:

```
.toggle( [ duration ], [ callback ] )
.toggle( [ duration ], [ easing ], [ callback ] )
.toggle( showOrHide )
```

However, the documentation also says that:

```
$('#foo').toggle(showOrHide);
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ( showOrHide == true ) {
  $('#foo').show();
} else if ( showOrHide == false ) {
  $('#foo').hide();
}
```

So, use that fact:

```
if (type == "A") {
  $('#txtA').show('slow');
}
else {
  $('#txtA').hide('slow');
}
```

And, no, sorry, you can't avoid writing it out like this.

<sup>It seems bizarre, anyway, to want to call a function named "toggle" but specify whether you're going to show or hide.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
if(type == "A"){
    $("#txtA").show(500);
} else{
    $("#txtA").hide(500);
}
```